# Visual Basic - Return to begining

Tags: if-statement

I am just wondering if there is an easy way to ask your program to return to the begining if enter key (or any key) was pressed. This means the output window will stay open and they wouldn't have to close it and re-run the program.

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your age")
age = Console.ReadLine()

If age < 18 Then
    Console.WriteLine("Not old enough, please enter age again")
    ' GO BACK TO BEGINING TO ASK THE USER TO ENTER THEIR AGE AGAIN
End If
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DIM Age as INT = 0

DO UNTIL Age > 18
    Age = Console.ReadLine()

    IF AGE < 18 THEN
        Console.WriteLine("Not Old Enough... blah")
    END IF

LOOP
```

(its been forever since I used VB the syntax may be off a bit)

EDIT:  You're going to want to check to make sure the console.readline() input is a number otherwise you might get an exception.

Good luck

Comment: Perfect. Worked. Thank you.